# Decrypting Windows EC2 password in Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I would like to launch a Windows EC2 instance and programmatically get the admin password using Python.  I know this can be done using the CLI like this, but I would prefer to decrypt locally to avoid sending my private key over the internet.

```
aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id i-0d4d8273cadcae0a0 --priv-launch-key .ssh/elliott2.pem
```

After reading Cryptodome docs, I tried like this:

```
import boto3
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', 'us-west-2')
i = ec2.Instance('i-028dee2acb533fc59')

encrypted_str = i.password_data()['PasswordData']
with open('mykey.pem') as fp:
  key = RSA.importKey(fp.read())

cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
print(cipher.decrypt(enc_str))
```

This fails with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(cipher.decrypt(encrypted_str))
  File "/Users/elliott/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 167, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

I think `cipherkey` must be exactly 256 Bytes.  But the password data is longer than this, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you sure `i.password_data()['PasswordData']` is not `''`? I ran into the same problem and found out I had launched my EC2 instance without a keypair, so there was no password in the first place.

Comment: Note that if you launched your EC2 instance without a keypair, or if the password for the EC2 instance hasn't been generated yet, then `password_data()` will return an empty string. For more info, see [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.get_password_data).

Comment: @ShaneBishop have you tried printing `encrypted_str` to see if you're getting the password or not?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, since I created the bounty for this question, I actually found a solution of my own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72410935/8593689

Comment: I can't close [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72407196/8593689) as a duplicate of this question, since this question has no accepted or upvoted answers. But, once I am able to accept my answer on my question, then it will be possible to vote to close this question as a duplicate of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Get decrypted EC2 Windows instance Administrator password using python boto

```
AWS_EC2_ACCESS_ID='AKIA**********'
AWS_EC2_SECRET_KEY = 'mh83**************'
PEM_FILE = os.path.expanduser('D:\\abc\\scripts\\s\\test.pem')

### Get Windows Admin password of the newly created AWS instance
import boto.ec2
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

access_key = AWS_EC2_ACCESS_ID
secret_key = AWS_EC2_SECRET_KEY
pem_file_loc = PEM_FILE

def decrypt(ciphertext, keyfile = pem_file_loc ):
   input = open(keyfile)
   key = RSA.importKey(input.read())
   input.close()
   cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
   plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext, None)
   return plaintext

def get_ec2_instance_secur_info(region='us-west-2',instance_name=''):
ec2_conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region,
            aws_access_key_id=access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

# Get all instance
reservations = ec2_conn.get_all_reservations()

# Get all the instances and search for the instance based on the provided Tag - Name
for reservation in reservations:    
    for instance in reservation.instances:
        if instance_name == instance.tags['Name']:
            # Get the encrypted password and decrypt
            password = decrypt(ec2_conn.get_password_data(instance.id).decode('base64'))
            return {'instance':instance,'ec2_conn':ec2_conn,'private_ip':instance.private_ip_address,'pwd':password}

# Looks like there are no instance with the provided Tag - Name
print instance_name + ' is not found'
```

instance_name = 'new-instance-name-tag'
node = get_ec2_instance_secur_info(instance_name = instance_name)
print node