# How to decrypt Windows EC2 instance password that was encrypted with a PEM RSA private key using Python?

Tags: python, encryption, amazon-ec2, boto3, rsa

I want to use Python to decrypt text using a PEM RSA key. Specifically, the text I want to decrypt is the encrypted password data returned by the [`get_password_data()` boto3 function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.get_password_data).

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150602/8593689), but it isn't working for me.

I am using [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest), which I have installed with

```
python3 -m pip install --user pycryptodome
```

My key file is a PEM RSA private key:

```
$ file my_key.pem
my_key.pem: PEM RSA private key
```

Here is my code, which is based on the answer linked above:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

encrypted_password = '<redacted>'

rsa_key = RSA.importKey(open('my_key.pem', 'rb').read())
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
password = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_password) # This line throws the error below
print(f'{password=}')
```

When I run this, I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'PKCS115_SigScheme' object has no attribute 'decrypt'
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shane/src/experimentation/decrypt_password_so_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    password = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_password) # This line throws the error below
AttributeError: 'PKCS115_SigScheme' object has no attribute 'decrypt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In RSA you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key. Did you mean that the original text was signed with the private key? In which case you would want to verify with the public key.

Comment: I fixed the wording in my question. I want to decrypt with the private key I have.

Comment: But you are using a signature verifier class: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html which implements `verify` not `decrypt`

Comment: The class you are trying to use is deprecated anyway https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/pkcs1_v1_5.html Quite reasonably, it suggests switching to OAEP padding instead.

Comment: I just blindly used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150602/8593689). What should I use instead for decrypting?

Comment: See the sample code supplied, linked above. https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/pkcs1_v1_5.html It looks like your import statement is subtly wrong.

Comment: I suppose (in my EC2 password case) I can always get by with running `aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id {instance_id} --priv-launch-key {priv_key}` through `subprocess`, and parsing the JSON output to get the decrypted password - though this only works if the key is available on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From digging through the AWS CLI source code, I found a solution based on the code in [this function](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/194101201f4c901c8944e91aa60f04f06c3d4709/awscli/customizations/ec2/decryptpassword.py#L96).

The reason I struggled with finding a solution is the boto3 EC2 docs don't explain that the returned `PasswordData` is base64-encoded.

Here is my solution (note that this solution requires the [rsa module](https://pypi.org/project/rsa/)):

```
import boto3
import base64
import rsa

def decrypt_password_data(password_data, pk_path):
    encrypted_password = password_data['PasswordData']

    with open(pk_path) as pk_file:
        pk_contents = pk_file.read()

    private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(pk_contents.encode('latin-1'))
    value = base64.b64decode(encrypted_password)
    value = rsa.decrypt(value, private_key)
    decrypted_password = value.decode('utf-8')

    return decrypted_password
```

Usage, if you have an [`EC2.Instance`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance) object ([`password_data()` docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.password_data)):

```
password_data = instance.password_data(DryRun=False)
password = decrypt_password_data(password_data, '/path/to/key')
```

Usage, if you have an [`EC2.Client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client) object ([`get_password_data()` docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.get_password_data)):

```
password_data = ec2_client.get_password_data(
    InstanceId='i-1234567',  # Replace as needed
    DryRun=False
)
password = decrypt_password_data(password_data, '/path/to/key')
```

If you don't need to do this in Python and you have [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/index.html) installed, you can instead do this ([`get-password-data` docs link](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/get-password-data.html); note that this outputs a JSON object):

```
aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id <instance_id> --priv-launch-key /path/to/key
```

Note the following from the boto3 docs:

> When you launch an instance, password generation and encryption may take a few minutes. If you try to retrieve the password before it's available, the output returns an empty string.